# Simple time tracking and reporting desktop software

Tags: windows, gratis, time-management

I found other questions on the same topic, I read the suggestions there and tried *Grindstone* and *Fanurio*, but both seemed:

- to be centered around project / client management (I've already removed them but IIRC Fanurio even required me to create a client to enter activities on a project, that's too much);
- more concerned about real time tracking (with Grindstone asking about the time spent in any window / application);
- not to have the tagging and tag charting abilities that I'm looking for.

Hence I may not have chosen the best wording for the title / my web searches, maybe the software I'm looking for belongs to a different category.

I need a simple Windows application, with the following features:

- ability to add time portions with the following info: day, duration, description, i.e.:

  - [1] 01/09/2020 5h added new functionality
  - [2] 01/09/2020 1h email and calls
  - [3] 02/09/2020 2h meeting
  - [4] 02/09/2020 4h bug fixing
  - [5] 02/09/2020 1h meeting
  - [6] 03/09/2020 2h installation & config
  - [7] 03/09/2020 3h software review
- ability to attach any number of categories / tags to each entry

  - [1] project1, development
  - [2] project1, coordination
  - [3] project1, coordination
  - [4] project2, development
  - [5] project2, coordination
  - [6] project1, sysadmin
  - [7] project2 review
- ability to later split / merge time portions
- draw charts (pie as a must, but others could be interesting):

  - projects: project1 vs project2
  - project1: development vs coordination vs sysadmin vs review
  - project2: development vs coordination vs sysadmin vs review
  - even cross-property:

    - development: project1 vs project2
    - coordination: project1 vs project2

This will be only for personal usage; it will be compiled after the time has passed, so I'm not interested in things like: start time, end time, activity completed and such; nor I need any application or webpage time tracking in real time, not even any billing functionality is required.

Comment: Best is to tell which programs you investigated and what you missed (and what you liked), this will probably result in better answers.

Answer (score 0):

**[Hamster Time Tracker](https://github.com/projecthamster/hamster-gtk)** fulfills your requirements, except charting which can be done via export into your favourite spreadsheet app (e.g Excel).

**[Task Warrior or Time Warrior](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taskwarrior)** is another (easier to use on Windows).

Wikipedia's **[Comparison of time-tracking software](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_time-tracking_software)**  lists many alternatives by Plattform and Features.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of others to check out:

[Kimai](https://www.kimai.org/)

- It is opensource.
- Can be configured to use just date and duration instead of start/stop times.
- Times can be entered manually, or use in-built timer if you prefer.
- For each activity entered, you can add description, tags, etc.
- Has a dashboard and some reports.
- Ability to merge times is not available. But you can pay project owner to add a new plugin to do ths. There are some additional plugins [here](https://www.kimai.org/store/).
- To simplify interface, you can remove modules not required.

Unfortunately most timetracking systems require Client, Project, but you can always use a dummy Client/Project e.g. "MySelf", "MyProject"...

[Traggo](https://traggo.net/)

- "There are no tasks, only tagged time spans."
- "With tags, Traggo tries to be as customizable as possible"...